# error 404 Spring Security 4.0 with primefaces

Tags: spring, primefaces, spring-security

I'm using a web application with Spring, Spring Security, hibernate and primefaces.
the probleme is about the authentication: when i don't create login page, Spring security creates one automatically and all work fine, but whene i create a login.xhtml page, i got this error: error 404 j_spring_security_check

the login.xhtml page:

```
<form action="j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Connexion</legend>
    <p>
        <label>Login:</label>
        <input type="text" name="j_username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="j_password"/>
    </p>
    <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My applicationContext.xml contains Spring security configuration is in Web-Inf folder, and the configuration is good.

```
<s:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<s:http use-expressions="true">
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />

    <s:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/nota/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <s:session-management>
        <s:concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </s:session-management>
    <s:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <s:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <s:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" />
</s:http>
<bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="primefaces.test.authentification.MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />



<s:authentication-manager>
    <s:authentication-provider>
        <s:user-service>
            <s:user name="jimi" password="jimi" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <s:user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </s:user-service>
    </s:authentication-provider>
</s:authentication-manager>
```

Can anyone help me ? please

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces releated? I just see plain html?

Comment: i already  used login form with primefaces components, but i got the same error. anayway , the problem is not related to primefaces or jsp or xhtml, but to the resource j_spring_security_check

Comment: What does your Spring Security configuration look like?

Comment: ok,  i will update the question

Comment: Spring Sec conf seems good, because if i don't specify the login-page, all work fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by changing spring and Spring sec versions to 3.2.4 
All work fine